# Email function not working

Tags: centos, email

I have this 3 commands. All of it are not able to send the email. Any solution or my mistake here? The OS is Centos 6.2

```
mail -s "a subject" ****@gmail.com
sendmail - "a subject" ***@gmail.com
 /bin/mail -s "TEst" ***@gmail.com
```

Comment: Is sendmail (or equivalent mail transfer program) running?  What is the error message resulting?  Have you looked at the man pages for the proper syntax?

Comment: @mdpc how to test is any of this is running? Any tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide an email body:

```
$ echo "here is the email body" | mail -s "Subject" user@example.com
```

Comment: I tried your codes.$ echo "here is the email body" | mail -s "Subject" *****14@gmail.com
-bash: $: command not found
Null message body; hope that's ok. I can see the message reach.

Comment: Do not type the $ sign. That is the bash prompt.

Comment: so it is working then right? How to decide if is using sendmail or postfix? I receive the email from root@localhost.localdomain is it possible to change this email address?

Comment: @user150063 - Please mark this answer as accepted and then post that as a separate question.